# Error multiple foreign keys in a table

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Can someone say me where is the error?

I have another tables ( `Tabla_Usuario`, `Tabla_Tipo`, `Tabla_Nacionalidad` ) and this one has three foreign keys.

```
public static final String Crear_Tabla_Receta = "create table "
        + Tabla_Receta + " ("
        + Columna_ID_Receta + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + Columna_Nombre_Receta + " TEXT, "
        + Columna_Imagen + " BLOB, "
        + Columna_Pasos + " TEXT,"
        + Columna_ID_Receta_Usuario + " INTEGER,"
        + Columna_ID_Receta_Tipo + " INTEGER,"
        + Columna_ID_Receta_Nacionalidad + " INTEGER,"
        + " FOREIGN KEY ("+Columna_ID_Receta_Usuario+") REFERENCES "+Tabla_Usuario+"("+Columna_ID_Usuario+")"
        + " ,FOREIGN KEY ("+Columna_ID_Receta_Tipo+") REFERENCES "+Tabla_Tipo+"("+Columna_ID_Nacionalidad+")"
        + " ,FOREIGN KEY ("+Columna_ID_Receta_Nacionalidad+") REFERENCES "+Tabla_Nacionalidad+"("+Columna_ID_Tipo+"));";
```

Comment: What is the error? Tell us Exactly

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, impossible to tell due to limited information, that :-

```
+ " FOREIGN KEY ("+Columna_ID_Receta_Usuario+") REFERENCES "+Tabla_Usuario+"("+Columna_ID_Usuario+")"
+ " ,FOREIGN KEY ("+Columna_ID_Receta_Tipo+") REFERENCES "+Tabla_Tipo+"("+Columna_ID_Nacionalidad+")"
+ " ,FOREIGN KEY ("+Columna_ID_Receta_Nacionalidad+") REFERENCES "+Tabla_Nacionalidad+"("+Columna_ID_Tipo+")
```

Should perhaps be :-

```
+ " FOREIGN KEY ("+Columna_ID_Receta_Usuario+") REFERENCES "+Tabla_Usuario+"("+Columna_ID_Usuario+")"
+ " ,FOREIGN KEY ("+Columna_ID_Receta_Tipo+") REFERENCES "+Tabla_Tipo+"("+Columna_ID_Tipo+")"
+ " ,FOREIGN KEY ("+Columna_ID_Receta_Nacionalidad+") REFERENCES "+Tabla_Nacionalidad+"("+Columna_ID_Nacionalidad+")
```

i.e.

- The 2nd Foreign key appears to be for the **Tipo** table but appears to reference the `Columna_ID_Receta_Nacionalidad` column, which would appear to belong to the **Nacionalidad table**.
- Likewise the 3rd Foreign key appears to reference the **Nacionalidad** table but references the `Columna_ID_Tipo` column which would appear to be from the **Tipo** table.